# CakePHP Routing URL

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I want to add functionality to check session ao. I created one function like `checkSession` in my `app_controller`. Now, the first time the application loads it redirects to the *admin/users/login*
page.

At this login form, if I insert correct data then it redirects to my applications home page. I have user admin prefixed in my `application.so` after successfull login I want to redirect to *localhost/appName/admin* so I wrote the below code:

```
$this->redirect(Router::url("/admin",true));
```

It works fine in local but when I upload it on server it shows me error like

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pms/app/controllers/users_controller.php:192)
```

The code on 192 line is

```
$this->redirect(Router::url("/admin",true));
```

Can you suggest me its alternative option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pms/app/controllers/users_controller.php:192)"

The "headers already sent by" message occurs when you print something and then try to set a header, like the Location header used for redirection.
Just make sure you're not sending anything to the browser (printing) before calling the $this->redirect method.